# How can I merge 5 lines in the last column?

Tags: html, css, alignment, line

In all the columns the information is different in each line, but in the last column, the information is the same...

Can I somehow merge all the cells in the last column and just write `30 dollars` once?

http://jsbin.com/tifuhute/32

Comment: The question isn't clear, what are you trying to do? Are you trying to center the columns or merge the lines? What have you tried so far that didn't work?

Comment: If I have correctly understood, he wants to center every value and have only one line (under the header).

Comment: Are you fetching the data from a database to fill the columns? To make the columns centered you need a bit of CSS.

Comment: A "view source" shows us it's all in a table. Do you want to get rid of the table? All divs? Why not just center the table and cut the last three rows?

Comment: I have just updated the question. Sorry for not making it clearer earlier.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to assign a `rowspan` to the last column of the first row of the table.

http://jsbin.com/tifuhute/33

Answer (score 1):

You can use rowspan attribute to do this.
Please go through :

- http://www.htmlcodetutorial.com/tables/index_famsupp_30.html
- http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_td_rowspan.asp